# Can I change the carrier name in the iPhone Simulator 5.0?

Tags: xcode, ios, cellular-carriers

I found [numerous](http://ioshouston.blogspot.com/2010/04/set-carriers-name-in-iphone-simulator.html) [instructions](http://hints.macworld.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=116511) to set `SBFakeCarrier` in `com.apple.springboard` plist but this doesn't seem to work with iOS Simulator 5.0.

Is there any way to change the carrier name in the simulator?

Comment: Might get some responses from stackoverflow?

Comment: Not off-topic, as it relates specifically to an app running on the OS X platform and is not necessarily a development related question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For my part, I was able to change the carrier name for the iPhone 5.1 simulator by editing this file:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/French.lproj/SpringBoard.strings
```

As the path suggests, I'm French. Switch to whichever localization you choose.

Inside this strings file (editable with XCode if it's a binary plist), you'll find a `SIMULATOR_CARRIER_STRING` key. Change its value, fire up your simulator, and there you go.

Comment: How do I get XCode to open this file with a correct encoding?

Comment: Dunno, I systematically convert binary plists to XML before editing them — use `plutil -convert xml1 <binary_plist_filename>`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [fake carrier hack](https://gist.github.com/3035167) for recent versions of the iOS Simulator which do not support the `SBFakeCarrier` hack anymore. Just compile the `XCDFakeCarrier.m` file in your project and change the `FakeCarrier` constant to what you want.

Comment: Works great in 6.1

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little tutorial that helps you change the carrier name even on iOS 6.0 and up: https://github.com/toursprung/iOS-Screenshot-Automator/blob/master/changeCarrierName

Comment: Just wanted to let you guys know, the new path for iOS 7 is: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/en.lproj